# asp.net mvc razor - how to break out of C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

If I'm working on a view in Razor, and I'm currently in a code block and want to output something, how do I do this? To illustrate my question, I'm using `echo` from PHP below:

```
<p>
  @if (Model.NumberOfWidgets > 100)
  {
    echo(Model.NumberOfWidgets);
  }
  else
  {
    echo("There are loads of widgets.");
  }
</p>
```

So I'm using `echo` where I want to tell Razor that I'm not doing C# anymore, I'm meaning this should be written to the output. How do I do this?

Edit: I tried Response.Write, but that gets written before the view markup, at the top of the page!

Comment: Relevant: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<p>
  @if (Model.NumberOfWidgets > 100)
  {
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.NumberOfWidgets)
  }
  else
  {
    @:There are loads of widgets  //or <text>Thera are loads of widgets</text>
  }
</p>
```

Comment: I can't believe I've never seen this before.

Comment: I prefer the `@: ` usage because you can use that for script breakout too. This way if you use `@:` it will make all the razor breakouts consistent.

Answer (score 5):

Begin your line with `@:` this will tell Razor that it's actually ouput that you want to show and not C# code.

```
<p>
  @if (Model.NumberOfWidgets > 100)
  {
    @: @Model.NumberOfWidgets
  }
  else
  {
    @: There are loads of widgets.
  }
</p>
```